# How to send mail using an gmail id using SMTP?

Tags: c#, email

I am working on a project in which I have to send mail to an another mail account.
I have made a Web Method in web service using a gmail account with port no 587,I am trying to send mail.
Locally it works fine for me.But when I uploaded this project online then the mail is not sending.It show the error.
I have also changed port no to 25 for online project but again it shows error.
Please suggest me something.
Can be there any other solution for sending mail ??

Comment: Gmail is probably automatically blocking the login because its from a different location then known. You can login on Gmail once on the pc your deploying to see if the issue is solved.

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Its going in catch block and showing exception of "Failure Sending Mail"..

Answer (score 1):

In any case, did you allow less secure applications ?

[Gmail Settings](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)